# Grunt Compass/SCSS not compiling

Tags: gruntjs

I'm pretty new to whole Grunt and SCSS workflow stuff and recently configured Grunt with a WP theme development that run under MAMP. Installation of Node, NPM, Grunt and its dependencies went smooth. However, when i make a change on .SCSS files, it doesn't seem to be reflecting the changes to the .CSS files due to following warning from compass:

```
Running "compass:app" (compass) task
LoadError on line ["55"] of /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- susy
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace
Warning: ↑ Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.
```

Not exactly sure what's up but obviously a communication issue between Ruby and Compass?
Whether it be incorrect version mapping or paths..?

I researched and attempted following:

- Uninstalled the current and installed new Ruby
- Installed RVM (didn't use it, just installed it)
- Upgraded compass to the latest version 0.12.2 and made sure this version is reflected in package.json for grunt.

Any pointers and advise highly appreciated!

Comment: Seems that it's looking for suzy, have you installed that?

Comment: As @steveax says, looks like you need the susy gem... how about trying `gem install susy`? If you do need susy and you're using the `grunt-contrib-compass` task you may also need to add it to the `required` option for your compass task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an option but you might look at PrePros (https://github.com/sbspk/Prepros). I tried for a while to setup the raw/core setup you are working with but it was just always quirky - not to mention super tedious to setup. PrePros takes all the pain away! Just a suggestion.

Related/Reference link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19866550/sass-haml-compile-on-prepros